# HTTPS for sub domains

Tags: https, subdomain

We need to have some modules, for example: admin, app API, website.
So, for website URL is https://company-name.com. For modules we want https://admin.company-name.com and https://api.company-name.com.

How we can make subdomains secure(https). To use same certificates as for website, or they should be separately new certificates? What issues we can have if we will use same certificates?

Answer (score 1):

You need an certificat which include all your domains and subdomains on the SAN ( Subject Alternative Name ) field of your certificat. The simplest way ist to use lets encrypt, which generate it for free.

Than you include this certificate on both virtuell hosts

Answer (score 1):

You can use cert-bot to get https certificate

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04

Just add all domains while executing.. so, your certificate will remain valid on all the mentioned sub-domains

`certbot --apache -d example.com -d admin.example.com -d api.example.com`